# I got error like Error: Cannot find module '@okta/okta-auth-js' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, migration

I was working on angular 16 and my @okta/okta-angular version is 6.2.0

I tried npm i @okta/okta-auth-js which make the application compiled successfully but itself gives Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for OktaAuthStateService

Comment: what angular version are you using?

Comment: Also all the code related to okta initialization would be useful. are you using APP_INITIALIZER for that?

Comment: 16.2.0 is my angular version

Comment: imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OktaAuthModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: OKTA_CONFIG, useValue: oktaConfig },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],

Answer (score 0):

I just removed import of OktaAuthStateService,which is never used.Thus circular dependency error resolved.And application run successfully